# USB device interface has been blocked

Tags: webusb

I am trying to use USB RFID reader in our website.
by using navigator.usb.getDevices() i am selecting my device.

open() and selectConfiguration(1) 
is working. but device.claimInterface(0); is giving me following error.

**An attempt to claim a USB device interface has been blocked because it implements a protected interface class.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chrome prevents certain interfaces from being accessed for security reasons. These interfaces are the following:

- audio
- HID
- mass storage
- smart card
- video
- audio/video
- wireless controller

These are detailed in the following Chrome web test: https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/third_party/blink/web_tests/usb/protected-interface-classes.html?q=usb+protected+interface&sq=package:chromium&dr=C&l=9

There is a proposal for WebHID in progress, however: https://discourse.wicg.io/t/human-interface-device-hid-api/3070

Comment: Hi, I know that's too old but I'm facing an issue. I tried to access mass storage device and it's blocked by webusb. The weird issue is before two-three months ago I was able to access it. Any idea why?

Comment: Probably a bug in the browser @OrBen-Yossef